# Data movement utility in db2

Tags: database, db2, db2-luw

Why the `not logged initially` option during the data movement is faster than using the `LOAD` utility in DB2?

Not logged initially Method:

```
db2 alter table tablename activate not logged initially

db2 insert into table tablename select * from tbname
```

Load Utility:

```
db2 declare source cursor for select * from tablename

db2 load from source of cursor insert into tablename nonrecoverable
```

Comment: Please provide additional details, especially the volume of data you are loading.

Comment: There are around 50+ tables in the database of size 52TB (DB size). The total time taken by load query is almost double the time taken by "Not logged Initially" method.

Comment: I'm afraid why i have been down voted for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your database size and performance question I am going to assume that you are using the Database Partitioning Feature (DPF) with DB2.

When you perform `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, this occurs in parallel on all database partitions – each partition is working independently.  With logging turned off, this will be quite fast (albeit dangerous – if there is a problem, the not-logged-initially table will have to be dropped and recreated).

When you use `LOAD FROM CURSOR`, all of the database partitions execute the SELECT statement and return the rows to the coordinator partition, which then feeds them into the `LOAD` utility.  The `LOAD` utility then performs hash partitioning to send the data back to all of the database partitions again.  As you can imagine, with a large volume of data, shipping all of this data back and forth can be quite inefficient.

Comment: Thanks Lan for your response! Kindly let me know which could be the favourable way to make replica of tables. We need to do this activity every month.

Comment: Either method is OK, which you choose should be a function of your application's specific requirements.